# Need help on a database design issue I'm unable to describe

Tags: database-design

I'm building a website to display starcraft 2 build order guides and I need help when it comes to storing the actual build itself. The build consists of multiple steps as shown below:

> 9 - Build Pylon 
>   13 - Build gate 
>   15 - Build gas 
>   16 - Build Pylon 
>   18 - Build Cybernetics Core

Now initially I thought I could make a builds table, each build would have its own ID, but I'm not sure how to store each step in its own field, or even if that's required at all.

The build itself would be shown as an unordered list on the website so storing the HTML for the entire build could be possible. I don't know what the term is for this kind of problem where you can have a different amount of data in each record and therefore you would require a different amount of fields. Any suggestions for best practice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a BUILD table, where you'd have one record per "build", and then a BUILD_DETAIL table where for each "build" you'd have multiple records; one for each item in the build.

Comment: That's a great idea! :D so each build detail record would have an ID corresponding to what build it belongs to right?

Comment: Yes.  The BUILD table would have a BuildID, and perhaps a BuildName, etc. and the BUILD_DETAIL table would have a BuildDetailID, BuildID, Sequence, and whatever other data you need.  Maybe you'd have a BUILD_ITEM table too where you keep a list of items, and your BUILD_DETAIL table would reference it by BuildItemID.

Answer (score 1):

Consider tables as follows:

**Owner**
ID
Fname
LName etc..

**Build**
ID
MapName
OwnerID
RaceID

**BuildAction**
BuildID
ActionID
Sequence

**Actions**
ID
Name
RaceID

**Race**
ID
Name

- Owner defines the creator of the guide only they can update/change it.
- Build defines one of many builds they may have for a particular map/race
- Build action defines the order of builds and sequence allows them to re-arrange without having to add/move
- Actions limit what data they can put in thus ensuring the quality of a build.
- Race limits the available action for a build to the race in question.

Comment: Very similar to what the guy in the other answer suggested, if only I could correct answer the both of you D: so the consensus is have a build table and another table with individual actions for the builds

Answer (score 1):

For each item to be built, you have one or more discrete steps, some of which must occur before others.  So you have an Assembly table. Assemblies can have sub assemblies and they too can have sub-sub-assemblies.  Each assembly has a number of build-steps.  You could do it with two tables, one of which refers to itself:

```
ASSEMBLY
assemblyid
assemblyname
parentAssemblyId  (references Assembly.Assemblyid)

NOTE: when parentAssemblyId = assemblyid, that assembly is the primary.


AssemblyStep
assemblystepid
assemblyid  (references Assembly.assemblyid)
stepordinal integer    (step's execution order in the critical path)
stepdescription

You could add tables such as AssemblyStepImages
imageid
assemblystepid
imagedescription
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me the name of what kind of tables I need, very helpful.

Comment: Sure. You can read up on "recursive structures in SQL" if you decide to pursue this approach.

Comment: Also, change stepordinal to "float" datatype for greater flexibility -- easier to insert steps without having to change existing step sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider a Build Table that has many "Steps", you want to show this with time, right? Also you probably have a finite number of actions, so I would do something like:

**Builds Table Sample Data:**

id  | Name  
0,Some-Toss-Build

**Steps Table Sample Data:**

id   |Time  |Action
0        9   0
1    13  1
2    15  2
3    16  0

**Actions Table:**

id   |Name  |Maybe an image for rendering?
0    Build Pylon    
1    Build Gate

Sorry about the formatting, I tried to do html tables and it didnt come out right!